# Read from stdout fd of a running process in C

Tags: c, file-io, stdout

After much search and confusion i have to ask....

I have a binary running that continuously writes to stdout forever in a infinite loop.

```
fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",msg);
```

Lets call it generator.

The generator sends its PID (by using `getpid()`) to another binary called collector.

As soon as the collector receives the PID it visits procfs

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char *generator_fd = "/proc/17163/fd/1"; //This is the process ID sent by generator
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    fd = open(generator_fd, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

But it prints nothing :(. Can anyone help

Comment: Can you run the generator inside a wrapper process?

Comment: Actually just got the "generator" party  to agree to let me use named pipes :)

Answer (score 0):

File descriptors are local to the process concerned. You can't read an fd belonging to another process like that. What's in `/proc/NNNN/fd/NN` is a symlink to the file / device that was opened. If this is (e.g.) a tty, opening it is probably going to fail, but is certainly not going to give you what was written to the tty by the generator.

It sounds to me like you want a pipe between the processes.

Comment: yes. But i cannot modify the "generator" it is independent and running on its own. Can i still create a pipe to it ? can you point to any example. Because most examples i see online for pipes are between parent and child processes or named pipes where both binaries are writing to the same named pipe

Comment: Either (A) use `generator | collector`, or (B) use `mkfifo` to make a named pipe, and redirect the output of the generator to that `generator > mypipe` or if you want the output to still go to `stdout`, `generator | tee mypipe`, then open that pipe in `collector`.

Comment: Yes that i already understood. But my specific requirement says i can't mess with "generator" i cannot make it write to a namedpipe. or cannot start it by passing its stdout to another program via pipe. I was looking at ptrace and from linux and i can't attach to a running process if i know the PID (which i do). does anyone know of any tutorial that how can i read data being written to stdout for an attached process ?

Comment: You *can* attach to a running process if you know the PID. Rather than doing this in C, perhaps you might try `strace -p[PID] -s0 -o/path/to/log` with `-s0` and a bit of perl or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the info. I am going to use named pipes